# Video texture not playing in final render

Tags: texturing, video

I've applied video textures to the front face of 3 objects in Blender 2.82a. I can see the first frame on the objects but once rendered the texture behaves as a still frame. ie. It's not playing as a video.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the problem only in final render and the video is playing fine in preview?

Comment: Thanks for the response but I managed to work it out. I've never used video as a texture before so I didn't realise that I had to go into the "shading" settings and specify the amount of "frames" that I wanted the video to play. The "frames" setting was set to one. As soon as I set the amount of frames the video plays perfectly!

Comment: Oh good. Please delete the question then. :-)